# Get rid of unwanted whitespace on an animated CSS slider element

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I've been trying to get better at CSS, and I'm trying to replicate a menu item, like one that you can get on any food delivery app. It consists of a simple card, with some text, a price, and when you hover over the card, a small "OK" translates left (see code or codepen link). The problem I'm having, is that I want an ellipsis effect of the text when the .slider class overlaps the text (when the screen size gets smaller for example, or the hover effect is in place). This is the intended end result (all pure CSS, no JS invovled) :

[image: menu item before hover]
[image: menu item after hover]

Once the .slider class is translated by 59px to hide the "OK", the text no longer takes up the remaining space, it stops from the position it originally was, making it look pretty weird. Easiest way to replicate this is to simply reduce the size of the screen. I must have tried at least 5 different ways to do this by now, but still not having any success, so any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

[Codepen link here](https://codepen.io/gareth-thomas/pen/bGmXyPa)

```css
body {
  margin: 0 13px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-container {
  max-width: 768px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 69px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4.01149px 15.0431px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-text {
  min-width: 0; /*for ellipsis*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-text p {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.price,
.check {
  width: 59px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.check {
  background: #99e2d0;
  border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  transform: translateX(59px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.slider-text {
  display: flex;
}

.menu-item:hover .slider {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="menu-text">
      <p>Menu Title</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
      <p class="price">40€</p>
      <p class="check">OK</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can not do this by just applying a `translateX` to the price slider. The `.menu-text` element actually needs to shrink in width.

Answer (score 0):

I've played around a bit and there's probably a better solution, but this should work:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 13px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-container {
  max-width: 767.98px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 69px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4.01149px 15.0431px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.menu-text {
  min-width: 0; /*for ellipsis*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-text p {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.price,
.check {
  width: 59px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.check {
  background: #99e2d0;
  border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  transform: translateX(59px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.slider-text {
  display: flex;
}

.menu-item:hover .slider {
  transform: translateX(0);
}


/* Added styles */
.menu-item {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.menu-text {
  width: calc(100% + 59px);
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-item:hover .menu-text {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="menu-item">
      <div class="menu-text">
        <p>Menu Title</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slider">
        <p class="price">40€</p>
        <p class="check">OK</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The changes to the css are these:

```
.menu-item {
      display: grid;
      grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.menu-text {
      width: calc(100% + 59px); /* when OK isn't visible add its width to the text element */
      transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-item:hover .menu-text {
      width: 100%; /* on hover reset the width of the text element */
}
```